# HttpClient slow to detect lost connection

Tags: xamarin.forms, connection, dotnet-httpclient

If I switch off wifi, HttpClient waits the full timeout before throwing an exception. From then on, it throws immediately. Is there anyway to speed up the initial detection of a missing connection? Or should I manually check it with a plugin such as Xam.Plugin.Connectivity?

Comment: check connectivity first.

Comment: ok, but immediately I've encountered the problem that my computer is connected to the internet but the plugin is saying it's not.